# how to get heroku scheduling notification (like facebook) in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, notifications

I am using Heroku scheduling in my rails app. I have one app where user can create task with start date and End date. There is one pending tab also where all pending tasks listed out. Now I am using Heroku scheduling to examine incomplete tasks (current date > target date) and send it automatically to pending tab with one email notification.

Now I want to add one notification in my application also where if user login then he can see all incomplete (or pending) task with one Notification.

How can I add heroku scheduling Notification in my application??

Comment: I don't know about [heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), but have a look at the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but I know about whenever gem. My problem is not related to task scheduling. For me heroku scheduler works fine. I want to add one function in my rails application where user can see scheduled task activity by notification (Like Facebook, Not by Email Notification) ....